# How to join two metrics by some column in prometheus promQL (for grafana dashboard)

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

How to join two metrics to have it on single row in grafana column?

*I have two metrics:*

deployments{label="xyz", deploy_time="2019",job="deployments"}

metric1{app="abc", deploy_time="2019"}

How to join these two by `deploy_time` in promQL in grafana dashboard that it will look like this:

```
DeployTime label app job 
2019       xyz   abc deployments
```